# Is there an expression or idiom that means "do something in secrecy but with a good intention"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What is the most suitable expression or idiom that can complete this sentence?

I want to do charity _________ (in secrecy) because I don't like showboating.

Comment: Idiomatically speaking, *quietly* fits the context well. It has the sense of not going to town with it.

Comment: (*secretly* or *in secret*, not *in secrecy*)

Comment: ["Anonymous benefactor"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnonymousBenefactor) is a common enough idiom to have become a bit of a cultural trope.

Answer (score 3):

anonymously

> anonymous
>
> ```
>  adjective
> ```
>
> 1. without any name acknowledged, as that of author, contributor, or the like: > an anonymous letter to the editor; *an anonymous donation*.
>   2. of unknown name; whose name is withheld: an anonymous author.

Comment: This does not cover the 'with good intention' aspect, and without this qualification, 'in secrecy' is hardly a suitable question on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following options.

> I want to do charity ***discreetly*** because I don't like
>   showboating.
>   I want to do charity *without **making a song and dance
>   about it*** because I don't like showboating.

ODO:

> **[discreetly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discreetly)**
>   *ADVERB*
>
> **1** In a careful and prudent manner, especially in order to keep something confidential or to avoid embarrassment.
>
> ‘Gift-giving in courtship traditionally was handled discreetly, with
>   men offering women small gifts on special occasions.’

TFD(idioms):

> **[make a song and dance about something/doing something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+song+and+dance+about)**   (British & Australian)
>   to make something seem more important than it really is
>   so that everyone notices it
>
> He made a real song and dance about giving up meat.
>
> Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University
>   Press 2006. Reproduced with permission.

Comment: I like *discreetly* but the *song and dance* option sounds flippant.

Answer (score 0):

***[without [a] fanfare](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fanfare)***

> 2. an ostentatious display.
> 3. publicity.

(Random House)

Your sentence:

> I want to do charity work, but **without fanfare,** because I don't like showboating.

Answer (score -3):

I don't want to draw attention to myself. Or perhaps I'm reluctant to toot my own horn.

Comment: This doesn't fit the blank in the asker's sample sentence.